# I want to make my GUI screen window size, not full screen

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics

I'm watching a tutorial on making a GUI and they're using the GraphicsDevice and GraphicsEnvironment for it. However they're making it a full screen application, but I want to make it a windowed application.

How would I go about doing this?

My code is here

```
public void setFullScreen(DisplayMode dm, JFrame window){

    window.setUndecorated(true);
    window.setResizable(false);
    vc.setFullScreenWindow(window);

    if(dm != null && vc.isDisplayChangeSupported()){
        try{
            vc.setDisplayMode(dm);

        }catch(Exception ex){

        }
    }
}
public Window getFullScreenWindow(){
    return vc.getFullScreenWindow();
}
public void restoreScreen(){
    Window w = vc.getFullScreenWindow();
    if(w != null){
        w.dispose();
    }
    vc.setFullScreenWindow(null);
}
```

Comment: Start with the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html). The tutorial has all kinds of examples that you can use as a starting point.

Comment: @camickr Is there no GraphicsEnvironment option to not setFullScreenWindow?

Comment: Read the tutorial!!! It doesn't even use the GraphicsEnvironment. There is no need to use the GraphicsEnvironment. So why are you worried about it? Play with examples and THEN ask questions.